# Can we run PBEh-3c in Gaussian?

Tags: computational-chemistry

Can someone help with with setting up a calculation to run the new composite scheme PBEh-3c in Gaussian?
The code has been implemented in Turbomole and ORCA and it's pretty easy to run it there. Unfortunately I need to run a supramolecular stack in Gaussian because it's what we have in the cluster.
Thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this could be solved by reading the manual: http://gaussian.com/dft/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is seeking direct input help to a quantum chemistry program. We are not the support hotline.

Comment: I would not have closed this, especially not as homework.